# NSFetchedResultController section by relationship?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview with a `NSFetchedResultController` as the datasource. I have two entities like this

```
Book:
(NSString*)name
(Library*)library

Library:
(NSString*)name
(NSSet)books
-addBookObject:(Book*)book;
```

I want to have the tableview to display all the data from Book entity grouped by Library relationship. At the moment, there is only 1 library so there are only 2 sections. Books that has book.library == nil will appear on top in section 0, and books that has a library will appear in the second section.

I tried this but didn't work

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Books"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"library" ascending:YES]];
NSFetchedResultsController *returnFetchRC = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"library" cacheName:nil];
```

How do I do that? Thanks

---

EDITS:

It did not work because some `library` is `nil` in some `book` objects. I had to add a isInLibrary attribute flag to book entity and set default value to NO then sort and set sectionNameKeyPath to the new attribute to make it work. That solution is not pretty. Is there anyway to make FRC to group by relationship that could be nil?

Comment: Please explain what didn't work.  And show more of your table view code.  My only suggestion on what you've got is to use `library.name` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` for the FRC.

Comment: FRC has empty fetchObjects. I think i know why. Because some user is nil in some book objects. I had to add a isInLibrary flag to book entity and set default value to NO then sort and set sectionNameKeyPath to the new attribute to make it work.

That solution is not pretty. Is there anyway to make FRC to group by relationship that could be nil?

Comment: If the sectionNameKeyPath is nil, CoreData normally logs an error to the console, but continues with an "empty" section.  You say "`user` is nil in some book objects" - do you mean `library`?  If not, where does `user` come into the picture?

Comment: Sorry i meant library. the app did not crash but no result returned to the fetchobjects.